# Simple point transformation in Geometry nodes and material distortion

Tags: texturing, materials, transforms, geometry-nodes

Is it possible to apply a simple point transformation (es. scale, in Geometry Nodes context) and let the applied texture follow these transformations?

The starting geometry is a primitive grid, created directly in the GN environment

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using this nodes setup, the texture will follow the scale transformation, as you can see:

[image]

here rotation:

[image]